# Creating a Chart with Highcharts in Jsdom with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, highcharts, jsdom

With nodejs, jsdom and the javascript libraries jquery and highcharts (highcharts depends on jquery) I am trying to create a simple script on my server from which i get the svg code of the created chart.

Problem: I can initiate highcharts on an element with $('#elementID').highcharts... but that does not work with nodejs, how can I properly call its function? ( $('#test').highcharts )

I have prepared the example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5se8rozo/5/

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env({
    html: '<html><body><div id="test">Div Content</div></body></html>',
    scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js",
    "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js",
    "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"],
    done : function (error, window) {
        var $ = window.$;
        $(window).ready(function(){

            console.log( 'length: ' + $('#test').length );

            //the following prints "html: Div Content" which is correct
            console.log( 'html: ' + $('#test')[0].innerHTML ); 

            $('#test').highcharts({
                xAxis: {
                  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                },
                series: [{
                  data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 
                    135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
                }]
            });

            console.log( 1 ); //this gets printed

            //following should print some svg content with chart, 
            // but prints "html: Div Content" which means the highchart 
            // function does not work properly in this script
            console.log( 'html: ' + $('#test')[0].innerHTML );

            var svg = $('#test').highcharts().getSVG();

            console.log( 2 ); //program does not reach this

            console.log( svg );
        });
    }
});
```

My example, when run with "node example.js" prints:

```
length: 1
html: Div Content
1
html: Div Content
```

-> which means that the program reaches "console.log(1)" and then prints the div content which should have been changed to some svg content, it does not reach "console.log(2)"

Comment: The code you show in your question is failing on `var svg = test.highcharts().getSVG();` because the `test` variable is never defined. After fixing this, then the code generates an exception on the same line because `test.highcharts()` returns an undefined value. The exception should be part of the output you report in the question.

Comment: That is correct, I have changed that. However the problem even before that is that  $('#test').highcharts ... does not work and my question is how to use the library's function in jsdom/nodejs to create a chart in the above div with id "test" (which workd in my fiddle)

Comment: I've used JSDom for years, and contributed code to it. I've not tried to use it to run code that needs to compute dimensions, because that's something JSDom does not do well. It does not *need* to render anything, so it does not spend much effort simulating things that pertain to rendering, like dimensions. I would expect that charting code would need to be able to compute dimensions and so would have trouble with JSDom. I've checked a few question on SO that talked about using highcharts with JSDom, and results vary wildly. Some people ditched JSDom in favor of PhantomJS, for instance.

Comment: I have heard of PhantomJS and tried to use it but it calls for an old "GLIBCXX_3.4.9" ..even the latest PhantomJS does, so i cannot use it until the update it

Comment: Have you seen this example?https://gist.github.com/TorsteinHonsi/e8a1e6971608523eb8dd

I think that good idea is to use PhantomJS, it is well described in Highcharts docs: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside